# Error retrieving registry value with Powershell

Tags: powershell, registry

I'm attempting to read a value from a registry entry with Powershell.  This is fairly simple, however, one particular registry key is giving me trouble.

If I run the following, I can't get the value of the (default) of "$setting".

```
C:\Program Files\PowerGUI> $setting = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\Autorun.inf" 

C:\Program Files\PowerGUI> $setting


PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
               CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\Autorun.inf
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\
               CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping
PSChildName  : Autorun.inf
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
(default)    : @SYS:DoesNotExist
```

Normally, I would do $setting.Attribute, or $setting.(default).  However, that results in the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\PowerGUI> $setting.(default)
The term 'default' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At :line:1 char:17
+ $setting.(default <<<< )
```

How do I get the value of the "(default)" attribute?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** Had to look through and old script to figure this out.

The trick is that you need to look inside the underlying PSObject to get the values.  In particular look at the properties bag

```
$a = get-itemproperty -path "HKLM:\Some\Path"
$default = $a.psobject.Properties | ?{ $_.Name -eq "(default)" }
```

You can also just use an indexer instead of doing the filter trick

```
$default = $a.psobject.Properties["(default)"].Value;
```

Comment: To add to this, in the original code the () instructed PowerShell to treat the text (in this case "Default") as a separate command.  When you have properties that have unusual characters like that, you need to quote (and sometimes use $()) the value like JaredPar showed so that PowerShell does not interpret the value as an expression.  Other characters to watch out for are $ . : ' " (there may be more, but that is all I can remember)

Comment: Using $setting.'(default)' to escape the parenthesis also works.

Comment: Just for completeness, the second example actually requires a .Value at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Another version:

(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\Autorun.inf').'(default)'

Answer (score 4):

Use `Get-Item` to get an object representing the registry key:

```
PS > $regKey = Get-Item HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\IniFileMapping\Autorun.inf
```

This gives you an instance of [`RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx). `RegistryKey` has a method named `GetValue`; if the argument to `GetValue` is the empty string (`''`), then it will return the `(default)` value:

```
PS > $regKey.GetValue('')
```

Why is this better than `Get-ItemProperty`? It extends more naturally to `Get-ChildItem`. `Get-ChildItem` will give you a list of `RegistryKey` objects. In my particular case, I wanted to list the install paths of the versions of Python installed on my machine:

```
PS C:\> get-childitem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\*\InstallPath `
>> | foreach-object { $_.GetValue('') }
C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\
C:\Python\27\
```