# Get the latest version of software from PowerShell and get the respective exe path

Tags: powershell-3.0

When I am writing any PowerShell script, I am hard coding the following paths to perform some operation

`Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" -ArgumentList $parameters -Wait`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe`

Instead I would like to get the latest version installed and its relative path this can be `C:\Program Files (x86)` either `C:\Program Files` or the other path based on PC configuration. So is there any dynamic way to get the required software latest version.

Some how I got this but I want to get the Property highlighted in the imagecan some one help me

`$inst = (Get-Item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe')
$inst`

[image]

Comment: [Error retrieving registry value with Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/q/799633) ?

Comment: Hi can I know how can I look for this in registry `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Deployment.exe`

Comment: The linked question contains answers that show how to get the `(default)` value on your screenshot.

Comment: Hi I got it visual studio I am trying to achieve the same for SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is the answer

`$vsPath= (Get-Item  'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\devenv.exe').GetValue($name)`